# VB.Net nested events not firing?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have an event firing which in turn needs to trigger one of two events based on some logic, but the issue is neither is firing.

```
Public Shared Event Kickoff(ByVal homeTeamKickingOff As Boolean)
    Public Shared Event KickoffRet(ByVal kickReturner As Integer)
    Public Shared Event Touchback(onKickoff As Boolean)

     Public Sub New()
            'MyBase.New(homeTeamId, awayTeamId)
            'Add Event Handlers
            AddHandler Kickoff, AddressOf KickoffEvt
            AddHandler KickoffRet, AddressOf KickoffRetEvt
            AddHandler Touchback, AddressOf TouchbackEvt
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub KickoffRetEvt(kickReturner As Integer)
            Dim MyRand As New MersenneTwister
            Dim GenKickRetYds As New MersenneTwister

            Select Case MyRand.GenerateInt32(0, 100)
                Case 0 To 80
                    KickReturnYards = GenKickRetYds.GenerateInt32(10, 30)
                Case 71 To 90
                    KickReturnYards = GenKickRetYds.GenerateInt32(31, 40)
                Case 91 To 97
                    KickReturnYards = GenKickRetYds.GenerateInt32(41, 60)
                Case Else
                    KickReturnYards = GenKickRetYds.GenerateInt32(61, 100)
            End Select

        End Sub

        Public Overridable Sub TouchbackEvt(onKickoff As Boolean)
            'If its a touchback from a kickoff, the ball is placed at the 25 yard line, otherwise at the 20
            YardLine = If(onKickoff, 25, 20)
            Down = 1
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Handles the kickoff Event
        ''' </summary>
        Public Shared Sub KickoffEvt(homeTeamKickingOff As Boolean)
            Dim MyRand As New MersenneTwister()
            HomePossession = If(homeTeamKickingOff, False, True) 'This is the same as HomePossesion = homeTeamKickingOff ? True : False in C#
            If MyRand.GenerateInt32(0, 100) < 40 Then '39% of kicks are returned, otherwise touchback
                Dim HomeKOR = FindPlayerId(Stats, "WR4", HmTeamId) 'Home Kickoff Returner
                Dim AwayKOR = FindPlayerId(Stats, "WR4", AwTeamId) 'AWay Kickoff Returner
                Dim KR = If(HomePossession, HomeKOR, AwayKOR)
                RaiseEvent KickoffRet(KR)
            Else RaiseEvent Touchback(True)
            End If
        End Sub
```

Neither the Touchback Event nor the KickoffRet Event gets triggered when its supposed to be.  Stepping through the code it gets to either of those lines of code and then just skips over it without triggering it at all...

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Where are your Event definitions....

Comment: Are you saying it *never* enters the other event handlers?  Or just not at that point where you raise the events as you're stepping through the code.

Comment: yes, it never enters the event handlers..it enters the Kickoff event which is raised from its base class, but it never enters the KickoffRet or Touchback event when it should

Comment: Event Definitions are up above, didn't share them

Comment: What type of app is it?  WinForms?  Command line?

Comment: Nothing obvious.  But a class listening to its own events is a pretty big code smell.  Events are useful to *other* code.  You can simply call the KickoffRetEvt() method directly.  Which surely ought to be Private btw.

Comment: It's in WPF but I'm using DotNetBrowser to integrate HTML UI/Javascript for the frontend and not use WPF for the UI cause its crap, lol

Comment: @MattE -- Hans has it right...why aren't you just calling the methods directly?  Also, use the most-restrictive access modifiers *always* in any code you write.  I know VB.NET has the annoying default of "public" which you always have to remember to change.

Comment: Hans, I haven't done much with Events so I'm sure there are some things that are not "correct" per se...

Comment: @MattE -- What Hans is saying is: forget events entirely.  You don't need them here.  Unless there is another class you aren't showing which also has event handlers for those events, and still, you have to have a good reason to model your application using events because it's a completely different paradigm (event-driven programming) which usually involves inversion of control, frameworks, etc.

Comment: OK, so I just call the Sub directly and remove the event?

Comment: I have the GamePlay base class that is running the game loop and then the GameEvents class which is a derived class...the GamePlay class raised the main event(Kickoff)

Comment: I suppose the more I think about it, the more I realize Events are probably overkill for this since it's self-contained.  Now in an instance such as League Calendar where various things need to happen from multiple different classes that are listening to the event, that would likely be a more appropriate use I am assuming...

Comment: I seem to recall there was an inherent issue with raising and handling events in the same class.. but for the life of me.. I can't find it again... However, as you state, why raise it as an event anyway.. you are just adding overhead.

Comment: Awesome...Changed it to a Sub and of course it works as expected